# how do i check to see if a double array contains a certain double in c#

Tags: c#, double

I'm using this code right now

```
        double[] LocationsDown = { 40, 85, 130, 175, 220, 265, 310, 355 };
        double[] LocationsUp = { 50, 95, 140, 185, 230, 275, 320, 5 };
        double curretangle = Math.Round(targetAngle);

        if (LocationsDown == curretangle) // <- Compile Time Error here
        {
            //thing
        }
```

but it says that

> " Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double[]' and
> 'double' "

I do not understand the correct way to check if the array contains said double I feel like it's going to be an easy fix I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Often when working with *floating point* we compare with *tolerance*, e.g. `bool contains = LocationsDown.Any(item => Math.Abs(item - valueToFind) < tolerance);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1):

```
if (LocationsDown.Contains(curretangle))
```

Answer (score 4):

In *general case* we have to compare `double` values with some `tolerance`:

```
 if (Math.Abs(someValue - valueToCheck) <= tolerance) {...}
```

When working with *collections* we can use *Linq* to query them:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 double tolerance = 1e-6; 

 bool contains = LocationsDown.Any(item => Math.Abs(item - curretangle) <= tolerance);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question I'm sure there are some benefits to using this method but since its simpler to use .contains and its just for space engineers script I don't think it will matter too much if its a little off thanks so much thou.